# pandas read_csv does not work with semicolon delimiter

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, delimiter

I am trying to use pandas read_csv to load a csv file where the delimiter is semicolon as shown below:

[image]

After I load file, the imported dataframe is as follows:

```
Eksamensnummer  Karakter    Unnamed: 2
0   138342349;="";  NaN NaN
1   138343311;="";  NaN NaN
2   4103308;="";    NaN NaN
```

In other words, it only recognizes semicolons as delimiters in the header. I believe the issue is caused by the double quotes in the file, but after searching for a while, I could not find a solution.

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: Have you tried `pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", sep=";")` ?

Comment: Please don't post images of text.  It can't be copied and pasted to try out code, plus in this instance it is hard to read in a dark-mode browser.  Make your question easy to answer by providing text input and your coding attempt as a [mcve].